# Youtube video automatically pauses on load in Samsung S6 device alone

Tags: java, android, youtube

In my app I've integrated Youtube player, and it's working fine in all devices except Samsung S6. I don't know the reason why it's not working in Samsung S6 alone, please please can someone help me out with this. Here is my code below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/close_setting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="closeSettings"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:text="X"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/close_setting"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"></com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
```

Here is the error below which I got...

> YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of
>   player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$FloatingMenuButton{1bb1e0b7
>   V.ED..C. ......I. 1280,2192-1440,2368}. Left edge 136 px left of
>   YouTubePlayerView's right edge. Top edge 344 px above
>   YouTubePlayerView's bottom edge. . 11-24 14:13:22.490
>   2057-2057/com.tamilflashnews E/onError: onError : UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY